# Spring MVC Non-English character

Tags: spring-mvc

Currently my web application (name, address, etc) accepts english and chinese character as inputs. How can I limit one particular field (e.g username field) not to accept non-english character ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put regular expression validation on that field. For instance by using JSR 303 validations:

```
public class User {
    // Allow only ASCII letters, numbers, '-', '.' and '_'
    @Pattern(regexp="^[a-zA-Z0-9-_\\.]+$")
    private String username;
}
```

then you would check for errors like this in your controller

```
@RequestMapping(value="/users", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String createUser(@ModelAttribute("User") @Valid User user, BindingResult bindingResult) {
    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
         // Invalid data entered ...
    }
}
```

You can read more about Spring MVC validation in the [reference guide](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html).

If you want to prevent user from even submitting a form where username contains invalid characters, use some client-side validation library (for instance [*JQuery validation plugin*](http://jqueryvalidation.org/)) as a complement to this backend validation.